# CSS - Adjust height to bottom of screen

Tags: html, css

I have a div with a big list, I only want to see (with a scroll) the number of elements that fits in the screen. So I cannot figure how can I adjust the height of the div to the bottom border of screen.

Do I have to use JS?

Answer (score 1):

If you got a fixed size above. You can fill the rest by using css calc.

```css
.test {
  height:300px;
  width: 100%
  background-color:yellow;
 }
 
.full-height {
  height: calc(100vh - 300px);
  background-color:red;
  }
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="full-height">
</div>
```

A better solution is to use a wrapper. Like this:

```css
.wrapper {
  background-color:red;
  height: 100vh;
}

.list {
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="list">
    <ul>
      <li>This</li>
      <li>is</li>    
      <li>a</li>    
      <li>list</li>
    <ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I changed my explanation, it was not clear enough. Your answer is right if the div is at the top, but if it is in another place? Maybe with more elements above for example.

Comment: I added an test object above. The only problem is, it's a little bit unclear. Do you know the height above? is it fixed or dynamic?

Comment: If now a better solution is to use a wrapper! will edit in a second

Answer (score 1):

Based on screen size apply media query styles.
for example Footer want to be bottom we use this for all the browsers

```css
html,
body {
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   height:100%;
}
#container {
   min-height:100%;
   position:relative;
}
#header {
   background:#ff0;
   padding:10px;
}
#body {
   padding:10px;
   padding-bottom:60px;   /* Height of the footer */
}
#footer {
   position:absolute;
   bottom:0;   /* Always make footer in bottom at any screen */
   width:100%;
   height:60px;   /* Height of the footer */
   background:#6cf;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
   <div id="header"></div>
   <div id="body"></div>
   <div id="footer"></div>
</div>
```